# How do I use linux processor affinity to dedicate 2 cores to user1 and 2 cores to user2?

Tags: linux, cpu, affinity

at first I wanted to dedicate 2 cores(4 threads) to one java PID, and 2 cores(4 threads) to the other. However the volatility of these programs makes me think that they will end up crashing and restarting. I have two users mc5 and mc26. Both run one process across 4 cores(8 threads). This causes performance issues and slight lag. I want to let mc5 use 2 cores (thread 0,1,2,3). I want to let mc26 use 2 cores(thread 4,5,6,7).
How is this possible? could someone give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?  Should work on already-running processes:

```
taskset -cp 0-3 `pid of mc5`
taskset -cp 4-7 `pid of mc26`
```

Comment: execvp: No such file or directory
failed to execute --cpu-list

Comment: doing yum install util-linux